# How to Center Tabs of wxNotebook in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, c++11, tabs, wxwidgets, wxnotebook

Hi am using wxWidgets and want to center the tabs in wxNotebook. The default position of the tab buttons are left(*screenshot attached*). That is they are aligned to the left of the window. **How can I** make the tab buttons to be at the center of the screen? In the screenshot two tab buttons/controls are shown which are aligned to the left. I have tried doing it by setting the style as wxBM_RIGHT in the wxNotebook constructor but that makes the tab go to the right side. There is no wxNB_CENTER, so how can I make the tabs stick to the middle of the screen? That is the tabs should be center/middle aligned.
The sample code is as follows:

```
MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString &title): wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title,wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(600,600))
{
wxPanel *mainPanel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
wxNotebook *mainNotebook = new wxNotebook(mainPanel, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(200,200),wxNB_RIGHT);/*i want tabs to be centered*/

wxPanel *tab1Panel = new wxPanel(mainNotebook, wxID_ANY);
wxPanel *tab2Panel = new wxPanel(mainNotebook, wxID_ANY);
mainNotebook->AddPage(tab1Panel, "Tab1", true, wxID_ANY);
mainNotebook->AddPage(tab2Panel, "Tab2", false, wxID_ANY);
}
```

My **2nd question** is that is there a way to give the tabs some margins? Like the tabs should be some distance away from the top of the window.

[image: Left aligned tabs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JasonLiam,

The answer to both questions is: You can't.

Centering tabs in wxNotebook is supported and is done by default on OSX only.

You can try to add a `hidden` tab, but I doubt it will help with the second problem.

HTH!

Comment: @jasonliam, they are not buttons - they are part of wxNotebook panels. So, no - you can't hide them. But you can switch them by clicking the button. Also try to build the `notebook` sample and see if there is another book control that will satisfy you need.

Comment: If you want a control with different pages where you switch pages based on button presses, there is [wxSimplebook](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_simplebook.html).  You'll have to provide you're own code for switching pages in the button event handlers, but it shouldn't be too difficult.